# How do I disable AOT in a Xamarin Android build?

Tags: xamarin-studio

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms project. For the past few weeks, I've been focused on the iOS code and haven't paid much attention to the Android side. This week, I got a more Android-specific issue so I tried deployment. Deployment always fails with the message `"Could not AOT the assembly: foo.dll".` "foo.dll" is an internal assembly made by another team.

No one else on my team is having this problem, but they develop on Windows machines. I'm on mac OS Sierra, and I'm suspicious something in the build toolchain's currently incompatible. But there were also a host of Xamarin updates before this started, so I don't know if they're innocent either.

If I go back in change history to branches I worked on a few weeks ago, I still get the error. I thought I could disable AOT, but when I check [Xamarin's site](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#aot) it implies AOT should already be disabled, and has been for several months. Besides, I don't have an Enterprise license so I shouldn't even be able to turn it on.

I tried switching to the Alpha/Beta channels. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xamarin Studio and all of the supporting libraries. I tried downgrading to the 6.1 version of Xamarin Studio and its support libraries, I'm about to try 6.0.2. The next most drastic thing I haven't done is reformat my machine, but I'm worried about starting that process if this is actually just a Sierra/current Xamarin thing.

The iOS build/deploy cycle is fine. This only happens on the Release Android build. I'm using the Release build because Debug builds are very unstable (this is consistent across the team, and seems to be an OS X tooling issue.)

I could probably solve this if I had a setting to disable AOT, but such a setting isn't present in the settings UI. Is there some super-secret way to turn it on we accidentally triggered?

**Update**

I do have the ability to deploy again. I downgraded to Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 and the Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android/Mono MDKs associated with that release window. This isn't ideal, I'd like to be able to upgrade at some point, but I think I'll sit tight until I get an answer.

Comment: Look in your `.csproj` files, do they have `<AotAssemblies>True</AotAssemblies>` properties in them?

Comment: @SushiHangover: yes! Changing that disables it. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one, as this is how I worked around the issues locally for now.

Comment: Have you tried out Visual Studio for Mac? Is the option `AotAssemblies` supported too?

Answer (score 3):

Search your .csproj files for this:

```
<AotAssemblies>True</AotAssemblies>
```

If it is here, try changing it to false:

```
<AotAssemblies>False</AotAssemblies>
```

Comment: (Answer from @SushiHangover, who neglected to turn his comment into an answer after 4+ months.  If he wants to post it as answer I will vote to delete my post.)

Comment: Is this option available for Visual Studio for Mac?